# Matching CSS which is not comment

Tags: php, css, regex

*I know there's been a lot of related questions but none seems to fill my specific needs.*

Basically, I need to match CSS code that is not a comment.
I've tried this (input first)

> foo

```
(?<!/\*)foo
```

but it fails not to match the following:

```
/* foo
```

and

```
/* comment foo
```

Also, `(?<!/\*\s*)foo` will cause an error.

PS For those who may ask, I don't need to care about strings.

Comment: You said this (`(?<!/\*\s*)foo`) causes an error.  What error?

Comment: @agent-j A lookbehind must be of a fixed length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the CSS you are working with is "valid" and you ignore string syntax, you could use a cheap trick like this:

```
foo(?!(?:[^/*]++|/(?!\*)|\*(?!/))*+\*/)
```

What it does is check that foo isn't followed by a `*/` (without any `/*` before it).

(You can remove the possessive quantifiers `+`, if your PHP version is outdated and doesn't support them.)